# GCloud DNS Nameserver change stopped propagating

Tags: dns, nameservers, google-cloud-dns

A few weeks back I have aquired a domain name on Google DNS and i would like to change nameservers to cloudflare.
Following Cloudflares Documentation
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205195708

I have disabled DNSSEC and changed Nameserver accordingly:

My Cloudflare Dashboard shows following Nameserves
[image]

Google DNS Nameserver Settings

[image]

I changed it last friday and its still not completely propagated.
ICANN lookup still show Gcloud Nameservers
https://lookup.icann.org/lookup

DNS Lookup shows a mix of old and new config.
https://www.whatsmydns.net/#NS/luctrate.com

Google api still shows old nameserver.
https://domainsrdap.googleapis.com/v1/domain/LUCTRATE.COM

Do you have any clues of whats going on here?

Comment: Looks like a race condition. Did you follow steps described here - https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3290309 ?

Comment: Thanks, I changed nameservers within the cloud console (where i acquired the domain) but I needed to change the nameservers within https://domains.google.com/ . To me it's an odd behavior, but it works...

Answer (score 1):

I can see that the record have been propagate correctly.
So to recap my comment for better visibility:
If you want to manage domains purchased from google on another website (e.g. OVH, GoDaddy, Cloudlare, etc.) you must change name servers on [domains.google](http://domains.google) as described [here](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3290309).

This change may take up to 72 hours, although is usually faster.
You can check current state of NS records with sites like [whatsmyDNS](https://www.whatsmydns.net) or by commands:

```
Windows:
nslookup example.com

Linux:
dig example.com
```